# How to detect reason of crash from Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am using Firebase Crashlytics in iOS App. It showing hidden line crash

**This crash has non-main threads that appear to use UIKit classes or functions.** Generally speaking, it is only safe to use UIKit from the main thread. Calling into UIKit from background threads can cause unpredictable behavior (like crashes!). Please double check that all of your code (that is not on the main thread) has been explicitly marked as safe to use in the background by Apple.

Answer (score -1):

It might be easier to find this while debugging your app. Read more about the [Main Thread Checker](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/code_diagnostics/main_thread_checker), you can turn it on at the "Edit Scheme" dialogue:

[image: scheme settings]

Does Firebase help you find in which view the crash happens? If yes, go there and start playing around with your app, until you get a message that your UI is being updated from a background thread. From that point, it should be much easier to find the problem.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for reply, Firebase does't show the view in which crashes occurs and 'Main Thread Checker' are already checked in my project.